# Java association

Tags: java

I have recently upgraded to 12.04 and I am using GNOME classic.

I want to run a .jar file by simply double clicking it. How would I go about doing this? I have OpenJDK 6 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a desktop file I wrote.  Stick it in a file named Java.desktop under `~/.local/share/applications`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Java (Jar)
Exec=java -jar %u
Type=Application
Terminal=true
MimeType=application/x-java-archive
```

If the folder does not exist then you can create it as follows:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications
```

Comment: I don't have that directory.

Comment: Then create it.